# What is the title of this book? Guy become involved with an organization that predicts and influences the future

Tags: story-identification, books

- I read the book circa 2000
- Fictional Setting: Modern circa 1990
- Main character is male.
- Guy appears one night at the scene of a crime he didn't commit, but
  has to flee.  He is on the run and is eventually contacted by a
  organization that deals in predicting the future and has agents in
  all different parts of society, business, and government in order to
  collect information, and alter events to go the way they want.
- It might be that information is fed into a computer system to predict the future, and there are event requirements that must happen for the outcome to occur.
- They influenced world wars, and the course of the planet in general.  Due to this ability money is not an issue for them.
- The main character gets a face alteration at some point and has to get used to his new face and identity.

Answer (score 4):

If you will accept a book with a woman main character this is a good fit for Michael Flynn's [In the Country of The Blind](https://www.publishersweekly.com/9780312874445) from 1990

> When Sarah Beaumont moves into an old Denver house, she learns that a
> previous owner, Brady Quinn, was killed in 1892 during a gunfight
> between two cowboys, seemingly an innocent bystander. Sarah's research
> into the mysterious Quinn leads her to a building where she finds some
> strange, abandoned machines, which turn out to be Babbage Analytical
> Engines (i.e., 19th-century computers). Soon Sarah is on the trail of
> the Babbage Society, founded before the Civil War, whose members use
> the science of Cliology to tamper with history.
> **Some of them have formed a splinter group and created Ideons (later called memes) to control an unsuspecting public**.

Sarah does adopt a new identity and face at one point; there is a male character who gets involved in Sarah's problems and also gets a new face and name

From another [review](http://alternatehistoryweeklyupdate.blogspot.com/2012/03/review-in-country-of-blind-by-michael.html?m=1)

> The story opens with the development of the Babbage Society, who managed to get Babbage’s early computers to work and create a genuine science for predicting the future. **The secret society, since then, has surfed the tidal waves of history in order to get rich** – they’re not out for power, as one character points out.

And

> History, if we accept the premise of the book, is strewn by the Babbage Society’s failures.
> **They started, more or less by accident, the American Civil War.**(In part three, this mistake is revealed to be caused by interference from another society, with both societies unaware of the other’s existence.) They played silly buggers with the American educational system to create a nation of sheep.